# How to get element within accordion event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the following script to detect click event so the accordion item expands and I need to get the `div` having class `.cellArrow`.

Html

```
<div class="cellArrow"></div>
```

JS

```
 $("#accordionContainer").on("accordionbeforeactivate", function (event, ui) {

       var cellArrow = $(this).find(".cellArrow");
};
```

The problem is that each section of accordion has this class so here I have the all `.cellArrow` classes.

**My question is how to obtain the `<div>` exactly within a fireing accordion element?**

Thank you!

P.S. Here is HTML I have:

```
<div id="accordionContainer">
    <h3>Item 1
        <div class="cellArrow"></div> 
    </h3>

    <div>First content panel</div>

    <h3>Item 2
        <div class="cellArrow"></div> 
    </h3>

    <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your full accordion section HTML code

Comment: @Girish Sure, Take a look at question.

Comment: see answer, would be helpful for you

Comment: Please check is any class added into your h3 tag if yes then you can use that class. Mostly it will add the open and close class to the h3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code,

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordionContainer").accordion();
  $("#accordionContainer").on("accordionbeforeactivate", function(event, ui) {

    var cellArrow = $('> .cellArrow',ui.newHeader);
    alert(cellArrow.html());
  });

})
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="accordionContainer">
  <h3>Item 1
        <div class="cellArrow">1</div> 
    </h3>

  <div>First content panel</div>

  <h3>Item 2
        <div class="cellArrow">2</div> 
    </h3>

  <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector should be:

```
var cellArrow = $(ui.newHeader).find('.cellArrow');
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#events

Comment: Hi need your help here on accordion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327296/2333214 if you have a minute to spare